# Looking for a jquery textarea script similar to mircrosoft office autocorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I'm looking for a jquery/javscript textarea script similar to microsoft office autocorrect. Using Microsoft office, I'm able to write things like <= and get ≤. Similary for those ones:

```
 >= gives ≥  
 -> gives →   
 +- gives ±  
 (c) gives ©  
 (e) gives €
```

And so many more. Does there exist some jquery/javascript script that emulates this functionality for textarea input fields ?

Edit: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently made something similar to MS office auto correct using jquery.
Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/73sEv/6/

```
function autoCorrect(searchString, replaceString) {
    $("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
        // escape some regex chars
        var escapedString = searchString.replace( /([\\.*+?|()\[\]{}])/g, "\\$1" );
        // finds current cursor position
        var pos = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
        // this turns the textarea in a string
        var text = $(this).val();
        //only search for strings just typed
        var stringToSearch = text.substring(pos-searchString.length,pos);

        if (new RegExp(escapedString).test(stringToSearch) === true) {
            //if there is a match put the replaceString in the right place
            var newText = text.substring(0,pos-searchString.length) + replaceString + text.substring(pos);            
            $(this).val(newText);
            //adjust the cursor position to the new text
            var newpos = pos - searchString.length + replaceString.length;
            this.setSelectionRange(newpos,newpos);
        }
    });
}
```

You can customize the way you want it. For example:

```
autoCorrect("=>", '⇒');
autoCorrect("->", "→");
autoCorrect("+-", "±");
autoCorrect("<=", "≤");
autoCorrect(">=", "≥");
autoCorrect("(c)", "©");
autoCorrect("(e)", "€");
```